# Firebase.database() is not a function - Sails Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, sails.js, firebase-admin

I've made a service called Firebase.js, and I am then trying to call this from my Controllers using the likes of `Firebase.database`, however I get the error *Firebase.database() is not a function*

**services/Firebase.js**

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var instance = admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert({
          [[cert info]]
        }),
        databaseURL: "foo.com"
    })

module.exports.default = instance;
```

**Controller**

```
    var db = Firebase.database();
    var ref = db.ref("my-db");
    var brandsRef = ref.child("brands");

    brandsRef.once("value", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
```

I'm not too sure where I am going wrong.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the code you use to define `Firebase` in your controller? From what I can tell, `Firebase` is not even defined. After initializing the SDK via `initializeApp()`, you should just be able to call `admin.database()` and it should work. You can use the app instance returned from the `initializeApp()` call, but it's not required.

Comment: It's sailsjs, so creating a service with the file name of Firebase.js makes Firebase global

Comment: If you `console.log(Firebase)`, what is printed out? I've never used Sails.js, but the typical way I'd handle this is have a file called `initializeAdmin.js` which checks if the Admin SDK has been initialized and, if not, initializes it. That file doesn't export anything. Then each file where you need to use the Admin SDK, you import than `initializeAdmin.js` file and then just use `admin.database()` or `admin.auth()` as needed. Does that make sense? Your way should also work, but maybe something about Sails.js is causing it to not work...

Answer (score 2):

**services/Firebase.js**

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

var instance = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://YOUR_DATABASE_NAME.firebaseio.com"
});

module.exports.firebaseDB = instance.database();// Export the database object
```

**Controller**

```
//Don't need initialize the Firebase again, only call function from service
var ref = Firebase.firebaseDB.ref("/your_resource");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  return res.json({MY_RESOURCE_DATA: snapshot.val()});
});
```

Where ***Firebase*** is the service file name and ***firebaseDB*** is the database object that export for use in the service.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should be initializing the database for usage. The code looks similar to this:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "Sample api key here",
    authDomain: "yourapplication.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "yourapplication.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "yourapplication.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "Id number here"
  };
firebaseObject.initializeApp(config);
```

firebaseObject would then be the object that you use for the database reference, like so:

```
var db = firebaseObject.database();
var ref = db.ref("my-db");
```

Comment: Which works fine until you need to use it in multiple controllers. At which point you cant use it because it's not included in that controller but it's already defined.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is your are using it in uppercase, use `firebase.database()`.

Answer (score -1):

in the controller you have to do

```
var db = Firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("my-db");
var brandsRef = ref.child("brands");

brandsRef.once('value').then{function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val()._name data from firebase__);
});
```

Comment: That's not what I want to achieve, regardless of that, it isn't resolving the Firebase.database() issue